# Beyond Compare 4 and Applescript

Tags: applescript, beyondcompare4

I know I can use Applescript to execute a Beyond Compare 4 script with:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/bcompare @\"/Volumes/SSD/My_BeyondCompare_Script.txt\""
```

This script actually contains something like:

```
criteria timestamp binary
load "/Users/.../_path_to_my_local_folder" "sftp://_path_to_my_sftp_folder"
sync visible mirror:left->right
```

Is it possible to write the contents of this script directly in the Applescript, without having this text file?
I'm not familiar with "do shell script" stuff.

Answer (score 1):

From Aaron, of Scooter Software:

> BC4 needs the command line "bcompare @script.txt" detected in order to execute in scripting mode.
>
> BC4's command line does support passing arguments into scripting, so the text file can be more static, while passing in the parameters (usually paths):
>   bcompare @script.txt "/Users/.../_path_to_my_local_folder" "sftp://_path_to_my_sftp_folder"
>
> where script.txt then uses:
>   criteria timestamp binary
>   load "%1" "%2"